# Excel Wrong Graphic

Tags: excel, graphic

I have this excel's file:

[image]

As you can see i also made graphic for it.
The problem is that it is wrong, because i have 2 same "periodo" (201603)
in the graphic, and i don't want it. I want to see it only 1 time, but with 2 columns on it.
Like in this image: (sorry for paint).

[image]

I already tried anything: I searched on google and  i aksed also to some friends. Please tell me where i'm wrong.

If something isn't clear ask me anything.

Comment: I have a policy of not answering questions that link out to images or code that could just as easily be added into the question.

Comment: Those link redyrect to an image. I'm sorry, but this isn't program. it's just excel

Comment: And od SO i can't add image without external links

Comment: ah. really? oh well in this case i'm sorry. i'm going to edit instantly

Comment: I see an icon that lets me add an image when I ask a question.  You should have done so.

Comment: i did it, but it doesn't show image too

Comment: Try adding two images.

Comment: There are already 2 images

Comment: I don't see images when I refresh.  Looks like you still have hyperlinks to external images.  I would recommend that you upload the images to SO.  This is my last comment.  I'm not likely to spend any more time on your question.  We'll see if others do.

Comment: @duffymo I believe you can only insert images into a question after you have surpass a certain reputation level.

Comment: @ForwardEd I don't know that, but i made it somehow

Answer (score 0):

1) rearrange you data so that each series, or each bar if you bar is in its own column.  See image below.  Bob Cat and Dog are the series names.  Dates are the axis labels, and the numbers of the series values.

2) make sure the vertical information is in the same row as the vertical information as the bar you want it grouped with.

3) right click on the graph and select "select data"

4) on the left hand side click add series.  Select the additional columns for the bar height.  make sure you include any blank above the data to keep the size line up with the previous.

5) your labels on the bottom will only show one thing.  I would suggest you use your dates. Use your legend to apply series names to the colours.

Caveat:  even when there are no values, the series still takes space.

#### Proof of Concept

[image: Proof of Concept]

Comment: Thanks a lot, but that's not what i want, sorry.
I want something like this:
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/kFkzfNM.png">

Comment: I saw that sample.  look at the data and graph above,  if you only want to know about two things, dont look at the grey column and and dont look at the dog column.  You will just be left with blue and orange.  The process up above is as close as you are goin to get.  in order to do it you will need to rearrange your source data.